# How to extract vocabulary from Pipeline

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-mllib

I can extract vocabulary from CountVecotizerModel by the following way

```
fl = StopWordsRemover(inputCol="words", outputCol="filtered")
df = fl.transform(df)
cv = CountVectorizer(inputCol="filtered", outputCol="rawFeatures")
model = cv.fit(df)

print(model.vocabulary)
```

the above code will print list of vocabulary with index as it's ids.

Now I have created a pipeline of the above code as following:

```
rm_stop_words = StopWordsRemover(inputCol="words", outputCol="filtered")
count_freq = CountVectorizer(inputCol=rm_stop_words.getOutputCol(), outputCol="rawFeatures")

pipeline = Pipeline(stages=[rm_stop_words, count_freq])
model = pipeline.fit(dfm)
df = model.transform(dfm)

print(model.vocabulary) # This won't work as it's not CountVectorizerModel
```

it will throw the following error

> ```
> print(len(model.vocabulary))
> ```
>
> AttributeError: 'PipelineModel' object has no attribute 'vocabulary'

So how to extract the Model attribute from the pipeline?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The same way, as with any other stage attribute, extract `stages`:

```
stages = model.stages
```

find the one(-s) you're interested in:

```
from pyspark.ml.feature import CountVectorizerModel

vectorizers = [s for s in stages if isinstance(s, CountVectorizerModel)]
```

and get desired fields:

```
[v.vocabulary for v in vectorizers]
```